# What is the Objective-C "constructor"?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, constructor, initialization

I have this class:

```
@interface RSSEntry : NSObject{
    NSString *blogTitle;
    NSString *articleTitle;
    NSString *articleUrl;
    NSDate *articleDate;
}

@property (copy) NSString *blogTitle;
@property (copy) NSString *articleTitle;
@property (copy) NSString *articleUrl;
@property (copy) NSDate *articleDate;

@end
```

Now, how will I make these member variables get initialized when creating an object, especially when ARC is enabled in the Xcode project? I'm new to Objective-C; I'm looking for something like constructor from C base languages.

Comment: `RSSEntry *entry = [RSSEntry new];` or `RSSEntry *entry = [[RSSEntry alloc] init];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Objective-C there are no constructors. However, it is a common practice to create `init` method and have users call `alloc` immediately followed by `init`. See [Objective-C constructors](https://web.archive.org/web/20111121033103/http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#constructors) for example.

Comment: Just a heads up that the link is dead. May be worth adding the code to the answer??

Comment: Alternate content for the broken link:  https://mycodetips.com/objective-c/constructors-creating-objects-objective-c-1734.html

Comment: @jwknz The link was archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20111121033103/http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#constructors

Answer (score 4):

you init an object like this

```
RSSEntry *e = [[RSSEntry alloc] init];
```

so you overwrite the init method.

Your init will look something like this

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if (self) 
{
    lesImagesViews = nil;
}
return self;
}
```

This is the init for a UIViewController subClass other class have default init that are just "init" with no parameter.